# display point with absolute size (diameter) from attribute

Tags: qgis, point, style, fields-attributes, area

I have a point file with an area attribute.  I've since edited the table to  back-calculate an equivalent circular diameter, with an additional field to suit (with a view to simplifying the procedure).

Can I style the point style to display points with an absolute size (diameter in meters) equivalent to the diameter (meters) attribute?

Even more preferably - could I style the point to display an absolute size (diameter in meters) equivalent to the area attribute?

Existing guides I've seen seem to make reference to styling tools in previous QGIS versions that now don't seem to exist.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your layer properties - Style

Click on simple marker, then look for the size parameter. 
At the right end of this line, change millimeters to map units in the list

Then click on the icon right next to that list. In Field Type you can choose the field of the table that will have the size value of your point.